# Codeception with Yii2, error when run

Tags: php, testing, yii2, codeception

I'm using advanced Yii2 Templet, when I run the test after built, I got the problem bellow.

**Idon't know what is the namespace, so please if you can explain to me what is it.**

Error

```
Please add `namespace` section into included codeception.yml file
```

codeception.yml

```
include:
  - codeception/console
  - codeception/api

paths:
  log: codeception/_output

settings:
  colors: true
```

Answer (score 3):

In `codeception/api/codeception.yml` file you should write `namespace` section like this:

```
namespace: tests\codeception\api
```